# UWP VLC.MediaElement to play video streaming while navigate back to current page

Tags: xamarin.uwp

VLC.MediaElement to play video streaming: the issue is when I navigate to other page I call pause method and then navigate back to this page and call play method but it doesn't play video streaming.

This streaming doesn't play on navigating back

I navigate to other page pause the MediaElement.
I navigate back and play the MediaElement by calling Play method.
But MediaElement doesn't start playing. It seems to me to be life cycle related issue. Guide me how can I achieve this.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (!MyGrid.Children.Contains(mediaElement))  
    {  
           MyGrid.Children.Add(mediaElement);  
    }  
       mediaElement.Play();  
}  

protected override async void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)  
{  
    if (MyGrid.Children.Contains(mediaElement))  
    {  
        MyGrid.Children.Remove(mediaElement);  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Show your effort.

Comment: @inullpointer I have edited the code

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?